# In django users should be able to see only the files which they uploaded

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a simple django website that provides its users with the ability to upload files. Right now all the uploaded files can be seen by every authenticated user. How can I make it so that the users can only see the files which they uploaded only? My models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Document

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'media')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

I believe I need to add a ForeignKey model to my Document class to trace back the user id... Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to make it work.
Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your Model Document add a field created_by with foreign key to user. Now in your view, return only the files created by the current user.

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then in your view

```
return Document.objects.filter(created_by=user)
```

it will return only documents created by the user

Comment: Thank you! it worked! I also altered my upload_document view too:myform = form.
                        save(commit=False)
   myform.created_by = request.user
   myform.save()

Comment: Glad to Help. Accept it as an answer to help others